# Margin error and vertical alignment on psuedo-elements

Tags: html, css

My HTML code is as follows:

```
<article>
    <picture>
        <img src="a.png">
    </picture>
</article
```

This HTML code is all over of the page, where the img has a variable width. The idea is to be able to hover on the img, creating a image hover overlay with a + on it. I tried that with this CSS:

```
article picture { position: relative; }
article picture:before { background: rgba(0,0,0,.75); content: "+"; height: 100%; opacity: 0; position: absolute; transition: opacity .25s ease; width: 100%; }
article picture:hover:before { opacity: 0.9; }
```

It works, more or less. My overlay is bigger than my img, always like 10 pixels, how can i fix that? And i want to center that "+" on my img, i cannot get that done. `vertical-align: middle` does not work, `line-height` i cannot use, since the img has a variable size. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you want the line vertically centered? or do you want the overlay to cover the image? https://jsfiddle.net/5f3pbg8b/14/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that images are managed something like inline block. You just need to use `display: block;`.

```css
article picture {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
}
img {
  display: block;
}
article picture:before {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, .75);
  content: "+";
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: opacity .25s ease;
  width: 100%;
}
article picture:hover:before {
  opacity: 0.9;
}
```

```html
<article>
  <picture>
    <img src="http://www.placehold.it/100x100">
  </picture>
  </article
```

**EDIT:**

Here's another alternative I did for the overlay you want: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rickyruizm/Lu8e0L4g/).